# Path error when visualising decision tree classification PySpark using dtreeviz

Tags: pyspark, classification, decision-tree, dtreeviz

I am trying to visualise my decision tree classification using the code in GitHub in the following link https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/blob/master/notebooks/dtreeviz_spark_visualisations.ipynb
when I am implementing the code:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("../../dtreeviz/testing/testlib/models/fixtures/spark_3_0_decision_tree_classifier.model/training_df")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most 
recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12920/640132816.py in <module>
----> 1 df = spark.read.parquet("../../dtreeviz/testing/testlib/models/fixtures/spark_3_0_decision_tree_classifier.model/training_df")

C:\spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in parquet(self, *paths, 
**options)
    299                        int96RebaseMode=int96RebaseMode)
    300 
--> 301         return self._df(self._jreader.parquet(_to_seq(self._spark._sc, paths)))
    302 
    303     def text(self, paths, wholetext=False, lineSep=None, pathGlobFilter=None,

C:\spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in 
__call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

C:\spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    116                 # JVM exception message.
--> 117                 raise converted from None
    118             else:
    119                 raise

AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/C:/Users/dtreeviz/testing/testlib/models/fixtures/spark_3_0_decision_tree_classifier.model/t 
raining_df
```

I followed all the instructions in this link https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz

I couldn't find the path in my local machine I am confused about what the code does as I am not familiar with Parquet format, it looks like a path but what does **.model** refer to?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look on the notebook. Indeed, it contains some unnecessary code which was used for development/testing.

In you case, the 'df' dataframe is not needed for actual visualisations. You can comment it and the visualisations should work.